# Disable arrow key page scrolling in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, preventdefault

I have a project where the arrow keys can be used as a method of input, in most browsers simply using `.preventDefault()` works perfectly, however Firefox (v37 on both Win8 and OSX) still seems to move the browser window (If there's available off screen scroll-able area)

```
$(document).keyup(function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 39 || evt.keyCode == 40) { // Right arrow, Down arrow
        evt.preventDefault();
        // Actual code
    } else { 
        if (evt.keyCode == 37 || evt.keyCode == 38) { // Left arrow, Up arrow
            evt.preventDefault();
            // Actual code
        }
    }
})
```

I've seen some things about using `charCode`, however my code does run so the `.preventDefault()` is defiantly being hit.

As far as I can tell, there's no reason this should move the window position.

Am I doing something wrong? Or if not, is there another way to disable the window moving due to arrow keys?

Comment: I think you have to listen `keydown` event instead of `keyup` cause the former is always happened prior to the latter

Comment: It's always the little things you don't notice isn't it, not sure how I missed that! If you want to add that as an answer I'll happily accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to listen `keydown` event instead of `keyup` cause the former is always happened prior to the latter. This mean that browser may respond to `keydown` event **before** `keyup` event is happened.  In this case you cannot cancel browser's response action (i.e. scrolling) from `keyup` listener anymore.